# Is there a way to get XML for Amazon's products?

Tags: xml, api

Is there is an XML for the products in amazon for my website?

Comment: please explain and provide more details

Comment: I want to build a website store based on amazon store (affiliate program) but wonder if they have a xml of their products, example for books?

Comment: Take a look at https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html: this lets you find product information and use it on your website.

Comment: check [Amazon Product Feed](http://apf.sourceforge.net/) project , download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/apf/) and see the samples

Answer (score 2):

I've used [Zinc's product details API](https://zinc.io/docs/#details-api) to get details (description, brand, variants) for Amazon products and it works really well.

If you're building a web store, you should also checkout [Zinc's order API](https://zinc.io/docs/#offers-api) to purchase items.

It's not quite XML but it's a solid alternative.

Comment: Whoever down-voted, mind posting what's wrong with my answer? I posted an API that provides the data John is looking for

Answer (score 1):

Check out the ECommerceService (aka the Product-Advertising-API), to retrieve lists of products from the Amazon catalog.  Of course if your selling amazon products on your site, be sure to register to become an amazon affiliate so you get a commission for the referal.

http://aws.amazon.com/archives/Product-Advertising-API/

This is a really powerful service, but it requires generating an encrypted signature for each call.

I've implemented this for a couple customers, email me if you'd like some help.